# xslt loop limited times

Tags: xml, xslt

Using xslt I need to loop number of coffee items but there must be limited - 20 times. If there are 10 coffee items, it need to loop 10 times under 20 times. If more than 20 coffee items, it is not acceptable. After loop coffee items, add them to CoffeeList node in a transformed xml.

And also if an coffee item has no value, ignore it. How to implement it with xslt file. Your help much appreciated.

**XML:**

```
<Action>
<Coffee1> hello 1 </Coffee1>
<Coffee2> hello 2</Coffee2>
<Coffee3> </Coffee3>
<Coffee4> hello 4</Coffee4>

<Amount1>1.2000</Amount1>
<Amount2>2.0000</Amount2>
<Amount3>1.2100</Amount3>
<Amount4>2.0000</Amount4>
</Action>
```

**Output:**

```
    <CoffeeList>
      <Coffee coffeeCode="hello 1" amount="1.2000" />
      <Coffee coffeeCode="hello 2 " amount="2.0000" />
      <Coffee coffeeCode="hello 4" amount="1.2100" />
    </CoffeeList>
```

**XSLT:** - I am not sure how to implement with this as i want the output.

```
  <xsl:for-each select="Action">
  <xsl:sort select="Coffee" data-type="string" />  
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 20">
        <xsl:value-of select="Coffee"/>
  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally want to avoid loops in XSLT.

Instead you select nodes and apply templates to them.

```
<xsl:template match="Action">
  <CoffeeList>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[
      starts-with(name(), 'Coffee') and normalize-space(.) != ''
    ]" />
  </CoffeeList>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'Coffee')]">
  <xsl:variable name="myNumber" select="substring-after(name(), 'Coffee')" />
  <xsl:variable name="amountName" select="concat('Amount', $myNumber)" />
  <xsl:variable name="amount" select="../*[name() = $amountName]" />

  <Coffee coffeeCode="{normalize-space(.)}" amount="{$amount}" />
</xsl:template>
```

See http://www.xmlplayground.com/E0eXFs

You could add a `<xsl:if test="position() &lt; 21">` to the second template to prevent further output, for example.

---

You also generally want to avoid "numbered" elements like `<Coffee1>` and `<Coffee2>`. If those elements are meant to represent the same concept (like, a coffee), they should all carry the same name.